# Alt text overflowing the icons in top bar when avatar (profile picture) is broken

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, profile-picture, alt-text

Consider:

[image: Username overflowing icon bug]

In Firefox (with ad blockers enabled) the toolbar is rendered like this.

Comment: looks like you have a facebook ava and its blocked by some  anti tracking script.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Doesn't appear to be an anti-tracking script. I tried to load the image and I get an error saying I need an access token to load the image.

Comment: Indeed, OP just hasn't set the right settings to share his avatar outside of facebook, probably his privacy settings on Facebook are that only friends can see anything on his facebook. Therefore SE is unable to get his avatar from the server and alt-text is displayed instead.

Comment: Upload a new avatar, the name won't show anymore as it's just the alt text of the avatar, meant to explain the image when it's broken.

Comment: The bug report isn't that the avatar is broken, it's that when it is (something the site can't fix for anyone, never mind everyone), the alt text overlays the icons.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is correct. Think we need to edit the body of the bug report as well? I've added the relevant tags that were missing earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's an facebook avatar. I'm not on facebook anymore but I created the account few years ago and don't remember the exact sign up method I used. These days I use email and password to login.

Comment: @Bharatvaj your current avatar is from https://graph.facebook.com/1570698936523475/picture?type=large. You may want to check your login options on https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current

Comment: Thank you @MetaAndrewT. and folks, it was exactly that. After removing facebook login and changing profile picture my toolbar is back!
Also I want to mention that toolbar was broken even on chrome where I didn't block facebook. I think it's a result of expired Oauth or something as I deleted my facebook account some 2 or 3 years back.